# Просмотреть список возможных параметров

Tags: visual-studio

Как просмотреть список возможных параметров для вызова, если их несколько? Типа

```
Console.Writeline()
Console.Writeline(String str)
```

Эклипс показывал их прямо в автодополнении (что было не всегда удобно, да)

Answer (score 1):

В зависимости от настроек - Ctrl+Shift+Space, R# показывает сразу.

Comment: Там показывается "1 из 2", как листать (кроме мыши)? Как выбрать нужный вариант? Ctrl+Shift+Space - это без решарпера?

Comment: Внезапно - листать кнопкой "Вниз", выбрать нажатием кнопки "Ввод".

Comment: Ещё можно нажать F12 (или правой кнопкой GoToDefinition) и посмотреть определение метода там. Можно нажать F1 и увидеть в браузере статью MSDN со списком перегрузок.

Comment: Стрелками листается, а вот Enter не работает. F12 - долго. Сразу - как в эклипсе?